# Refreshing BeautifulSoup in Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, beautifulsoup

Trying to run my script on a loop so that the information gathered from a webpage using BeautifulSoup is refreshed ever X seconds. This needs happen while Tkinter is running and the information needs to be displayed.

I'm currently finding that I cannot loop the script at all. This is my script

```
    import tkinter as tk
    root = tk=Tk()
    root.title('Title')
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Navigable String
    import requests
    import time

    page = requests.get("http://yourpage.com")
    #get info from page

    canvas.create_text(100, 100 text="text")
    #display info

    root.after(100,update)
    root.mainloop()
```

I tried putting `while True:` in however I had no success with this. I think it could be down to `root.mainloop()` but I don't know how to get around this because without that the GUI doesn't open.

**EDIT**

```
This is my code and it works where it will refresh, however, I don't think this is the proper way of doing it:

import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('title')
screen = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=600, background='gray15')
screen.grid()
root.iconbitmap(r'C:\\path\to\file.ico')
while True:

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
    import requests
    import time
    #SWDL Current
    page = requests.get("https://yourwebpage.com")
    page = requests.get("https://yourwebpage.com/page", cookies=page.cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    soup.find_all('td')
    yourdata = soup.find_all('td')[12].get_text()

    vara = yourdata[0:1]
    varb = yourdata[1:2]
    varc = yourdata[2:3]
    var1 = int(vara)
    var2 = int(varb)
    var3 = int(varc)

    offsets = (
        (0, 0, 1, 0),  # top
        (1, 0, 1, 1),  # upper right
        (1, 1, 1, 2),  # lower right
        (0, 2, 1, 2),  # bottom
        (0, 1, 0, 2),  # lower left
        (0, 0, 0, 1),  # upper left
        (0, 1, 1, 1),  # middle
    )
    # Segments used for each digit; 0, 1 = off, on.
    digits = (
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),  # 0
        (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),  # 1
        (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),  # 2
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),  # 3
        (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),  # 4
        (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),  # 5
        (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),  # 6
        (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),  # 7
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),  # 8
        (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),  # 9
    )

    if yourdata == 'x':
        class Digit:
            def __init__(self, canvas, x=10, y=10, length=20, width=4):
                self.canvas = canvas
                l = length
                self.segs = []
                canvas.create_line(250, 53, 270, 8, width=3, fill="snow")
                canvas.create_oval(250, 10, 255, 15, outline="snow", fill="snow", width=0)
                canvas.create_oval(265, 46, 270, 51, outline="snow", fill="snow", width=0)
                canvas.create_text(70, 30, text='info', font=('OCR A Extended', '18'), fill='snow')
                for x0, y0, x1, y1 in offsets:
                    self.segs.append(canvas.create_line(
                        x + x0*l, y + y0*l, x + x1*l, y + y1*l,
                        width=width, state = 'hidden', fill='snow'))
            def show(self, num):
                for iid, on in zip(self.segs, digits[num]):
                    self.canvas.itemconfigure(iid, state = 'normal' if on else 'hidden')

        dig = Digit(screen, 160, 10) ##
        dig1 = Digit(screen, 190, 10) ##
        dig2 = Digit(screen, 220, 10) ##
        n = 0
        def update():
            global n
            dig.show(var1)
            dig1.show(var2)
            dig2.show(var3)
            n = (n+1) % 10
            root.after(1000, update)
    else:
        class Digit:
            def __init__(self, canvas, x=10, y=10, length=20, width=4):
                self.canvas = canvas
                l = length
                self.segs = []
                canvas.create_line(220, 53, 240, 8, width=3, fill="snow")
                canvas.create_oval(220, 15, 225, 10, outline="snow", fill="snow", width=0)
                canvas.create_oval(235, 46, 240, 51, outline="snow", fill="snow", width=0)
                canvas.create_text(70, 30, text='info', font=('OCR A Extended', '18'), fill='snow')
                for x0, y0, x1, y1 in offsets:
                    self.segs.append(canvas.create_line(
                        x + x0*l, y + y0*l, x + x1*l, y + y1*l,
                        width=width, state = 'hidden', fill='ghost white'))
            def show(self, num):
                for iid, on in zip(self.segs, digits[num]):
                    self.canvas.itemconfigure(iid, state = 'normal' if on else 'hidden')

        dig = Digit(screen, 160, 10) ##
        dig1 = Digit(screen, 190, 10) ##
        n = 0
        def update():
            global n
            dig.show(var1)
            dig1.show(var2) ## Control what you want to show here , eg (n+1)%10
            n = (n+1) % 10
            root.after(1000, update)
    root.after(1000, update)
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
```

Or if there is a way to only update beautifulsoup that could work too.

Any help is apprecaited

Comment: You need to build a function that updates the canvas. Use the `after()` method to call the function ever 1/10 of a second. Your example cannot be tested btw. You are missing the canvas and whatever `update` refers to.

Comment: @hegash do not edit the OP's code. Issues related to the OP's code may be lost due to edits and make it more difficult to troubleshoot the OP's issue. When editing you should focus on grammar, spelling and formatting. Not the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a bit sparse and not something we can test. However a simple solutions is to create a function that can be called at whatever time interval you need.

Here is a basic example:

```
def update_canvas():
    canvas.delete("all")
    canvas.create_text(100, 100, text=data_gathered)
    root.after(100, update_canvas)

update_canvas()
```

By using `after()` within the function you can avoid blocking the main loop and be able to keep a constant update going.

Edit:

Your full code is a little hard to test due to this line:

```
yourdata = soup.find_all('td')[12].get_text()
```

Without knowing the url meant for this there is no way I can produce results.
That said I have reworked your code a bit to something that should work better with the mainloop. Thought it should all be converted into OOP at some point so you can avoid global.

```
import tkinter as tk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('title')
screen = tk.Canvas(root, width=400, height=600, background='gray15')
screen.grid()

url_to_request = "https://google.com"
page = requests.get(url_to_request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('td')
yourdata = soup.find_all('td')[12].get_text()
var1 = int(yourdata[0:1])
var2 = int(yourdata[1:2])
var3 = int(yourdata[2:3])

offsets = (
    (0, 0, 1, 0),  # top
    (1, 0, 1, 1),  # upper right
    (1, 1, 1, 2),  # lower right
    (0, 2, 1, 2),  # bottom
    (0, 1, 0, 2),  # lower left
    (0, 0, 0, 1),  # upper left
    (0, 1, 1, 1),  # middle
    )

digits = (
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0),  # 0
    (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),  # 1
    (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),  # 2
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1),  # 3
    (0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),  # 4
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),  # 5
    (1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),  # 6
    (1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),  # 7
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),  # 8
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),  # 9
    )


def update(if_else_var):
    global dig, dig1, dig2, n
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_to_request).content, 'html.parser')
    yourdata = soup.find_all('td')[12].get_text()
    var1 = int(yourdata[0:1])
    var2 = int(yourdata[1:2])
    var3 = int(yourdata[2:3])
    dig.show(var1)
    dig1.show(var2)
    if if_else_var:
        dig2.show(var3)
    n = (n+1) % 10
    root.after(1000, update, if_else_var)

if yourdata == 'x':
    global dig, dig1, dig2, n

    class Digit:
        def __init__(self, canvas, x=10, y=10, length=20, width=4):
            self.canvas = canvas
            canvas.delete('all')
            l = length
            self.segs = []
            canvas.create_line(250, 53, 270, 8, width=3, fill="snow")
            canvas.create_oval(250, 10, 255, 15, outline="snow", fill="snow", width=0)
            canvas.create_oval(265, 46, 270, 51, outline="snow", fill="snow", width=0)
            canvas.create_text(70, 30, text='info', font=('OCR A Extended', '18'), fill='snow')
            for x0, y0, x1, y1 in offsets:
                self.segs.append(canvas.create_line(x + x0*l, y + y0*l, x + x1*l, y + y1*l,
                                                    width=width, state='hidden', fill='snow'))

        def show(self, num):
            for iid, on in zip(self.segs, digits[num]):
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(iid, state='normal' if on else 'hidden')

    dig = Digit(screen, 160, 10)
    dig1 = Digit(screen, 190, 10)
    dig2 = Digit(screen, 220, 10)
    n = 0
    update(True)
else:

    class Digit:
        def __init__(self, canvas, x=10, y=10, length=20, width=4):
            self.canvas = canvas
            canvas.delete('all')
            l = length
            self.segs = []
            canvas.create_line(220, 53, 240, 8, width=3, fill="snow")
            canvas.create_oval(220, 15, 225, 10, outline="snow", fill="snow", width=0)
            canvas.create_oval(235, 46, 240, 51, outline="snow", fill="snow", width=0)
            canvas.create_text(70, 30, text='info', font=('OCR A Extended', '18'), fill='snow')
            for x0, y0, x1, y1 in offsets:
                self.segs.append(canvas.create_line(
                    x + x0*l, y + y0*l, x + x1*l, y + y1*l,
                    width=width, state='hidden', fill='ghost white'))

        def show(self, num):
            for iid, on in zip(self.segs, digits[num]):
                self.canvas.itemconfigure(iid, state='normal' if on else 'hidden')

    dig = Digit(screen, 160, 10)
    dig1 = Digit(screen, 190, 10)
    n = 0
    update(False)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @JackU well you to provide a testable example. As it stands now your root window is set up wrong and you do not have a working canvas so we cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: I tried this and still had no success. I have just found using `root.update_idletasks()` and `root.update()` in `while True:` to work. I moved the canvas out of the loop and it all works great, I appreciate your help

Comment: @JackU using update in a while statement is not how you want to do this. You should let the mainloop work as it was meant to. Please update you example with something testable so we can provide a proper solution that is not using a while loop.

Comment: Updated original question to include code, hopefully this will help

Comment: @JackU what exactly are var1, var2 and var3? You do not define them in your code.

Comment: Apologies, have now included those

Comment: @JackU I have updated your code. Let me know if it helps. I cannot test it without a url so no way for me to be sure at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer I'm afraid as I don't have much time

In cases like this where you need two loops running at once, python's built in threading module is your best friend.

Take a simple example:

Have a counter print a count whilst Tkinter window is open

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading


def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.mainloop()


count = 0
def counter():
    global count
    while True:
        count += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        print count


threads = []
countbot = threading.Thread(target=counter)
threads.append(countbot)
countbot.start()

gui()
```

You can obviously substitute the counter for anything.

This ought to send you on the right path.

Good luck!

Edit:

I'm not sure how familiar you are with threading; To quickly explain what is going on here:

Your code gets stuck on the first loop, and will stay looping forever, and not get to any of the other code. Threading runs multiple parts of your script at once, so the loop can run in the background whilst the rest of the code goes on.